# Trigger on ContentDocumentLink object which sends an email each time i upload a file in account object

Tags: apex, trigger, account, contentdocument

Things I have done:This is my code.Earlier I had done it without using an email template by using a subject and body in my apex code itself.It worked fine and each time I uploaded a file in account object I got an email.Now I am trying to do the same using an email template.

Error I faced:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LVvX.jpg
Is it because of some settings in the content version.I tried changing all of those.Please help.

My code:

```
trigger TriggerEmails on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
    ContentDocumentLink doclink= new ContentDocumentLink ();   
        List<Id> con = new List<Id>();
    List<ContentDocumentLink> doclinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

try{
    for(ContentDocumentLink c : Trigger.new){
       con.add(c.LinkedEntityId); 
    }    

    doclinks= [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId in:con];
}catch(Exception e){  
}


EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name ='emailtemplate'];
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();   
    
 for(ContentDocumentLink co : trigger.new){     
      if(docLinks!=null){           
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        
           List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
     mail.setReplyTo('admin@myorg.com');  
      mail.setSenderDisplayName('Email Notification');
     mail.setSubject('File Upload');
      String body = 'Upload ';
      body += 'New file has been uploaded';
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
      mail.setHtmlBody(body);
      mails.add(mail);
  }
```

}

```
 if(mails.size()>0)    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();` but not added the email address to the List. Because of this it is causing the issue. Can you add some email id whom to send the email as below.

```
 List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
         sendTo.add('sample@gmail.com');
```

This should solve the issue.